# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Memory Usage unusually high

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and is drawing over 1 GB memory every time it is launched.  Often the program becomes unresponsive.  Even when no queries are running.  I was using it yesterday with no problems.  I don't believe that I made any changes that would impact Management Studio.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Any Add-ins installed?

Comment: nope. Its pretty much the default install of SSMS 2014

Comment: Does it do this if you don't connect to a server?  (hit cancel on connect prompt)  I find the Intellisense/Auto-Complete can cause lag until the server tables/columns are all cached.

Comment: It seems to be only when I am connected to the Server.

Comment: That's not typical behavior. Is it the same for any server you connect to? When it connects to an instance, it only does basic enumeration of the top level objects. Even if you have hundreds of databases in the instance and each database has thousands of objects, initial connection to the instance does not walk all the objects. Problem is likely somewhere else. Perhaps some logon trigger gone wild or metadata corruption.